# Doctrine 2 annotation issue

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm writing my own CMS with Doctrine 2.5.4 and pure php 5.

**This is [my CMS](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzZZN5V9Ma4pUjRZVGNxc1BLajg)( GOOGLE link).**

while building, i countered this error:

> ERROR NewsDAO: exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class "News" is not a valid entity or mapped super class.' in /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:346 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php(91): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::classIsNotAValidEntityOrMappedSuperClass('News') #1 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(151): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass('News', Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)) #2 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(332): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), NULL, false, Array) #3 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(78): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('News') #4 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(216): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('News') #5 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(281): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('News') #6 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Repository/DefaultRepositoryFactory.php(44): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getClassMetadata('News') #7 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(698): Doctrine\ORM\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->getRepository(Object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager), 'News') #8 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/DAO/newsDAO.php(13): Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository('News') #9 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/handler/indexHDL.php(5): NewsDAO->getAll() #10 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/manager/router.php(22): require_once('/var/www/html/l...') #11 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/manager/router.php(18): Router->view('index') #12 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/manager/router.php(13): Router->routing() #13 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/manager/router.php(8): Router->__construct() #14 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/manager/CMS.php(11): Router->getInstance() #15 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/manager/CMS.php(6): CMS->__construct() #16 /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/index.php(18): CMS::getInstance() #17 {main}
>   Notice: Undefined variable: rs in /var/www/html/xxxxx.com/public_html/DAO/newsDAO.php on line 17

My `newsDAO.php`

```
<?php
require_once MDLDIR."news.php";
class NewsDAO{
public function __construct(){}

public function getAll(){   
    global $em; 
    //$tables = $em->getConnection()->getSchemaManager()->listTables();
    //var_dump($tables)--> return a lot of things from database;
    //$classes = array();
    //$metas = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata(); 
    //foreach ($metas as $meta) {
    //  $classes[] = $meta->getName();
    //}
    //var_dump($classes);exit();-->  return array(0){}
    try{    
        //global $em;
        $rs = $em->getRepository("News")->findAll();
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo "ERROR NewsDAO: ".$e;
    }       
    return $rs;
  }             
}
?>
```

My entity is `news.php`:

```
<?php
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
/**
*   @ORM\Entity 
*   @ORM\Table(name="Rich_news")
*/
class News{

/**
*   @nid 
*   @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*   @ORM\GeneratedValue     
*/
public $id;
/** @author @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
public $author;
/** @date @ORM\Column(type="integer")*/
public $date;
/** @title @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
public $title;
/**@content @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
public $content;
/**@full @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
public $full;
/**@title_en @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
public $title_en;
/**@content_en @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
public $content_en;
/**@full_en @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
public $full_en;
/**@flink @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
public $flink;
/**@img @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
public $img;    
}
?>
```

My table `Rich_news` in mysql:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| nid        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| author     | varchar(50)  | NO   |     |         |                |
| date       | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| title      | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| content    | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| full       | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title_en   | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| content_en | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| full_en    | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| flink      | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| img        | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

My `Config.php`:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",true); 
define('TIMER_START', microtime( true ) );  
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define('ROOT_DIR', realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ). DS );   
define('DAODIR', ROOT_DIR.'DAO'.DS );
define('MNGDIR', ROOT_DIR.'manager'.DS );
define('HDLDIR' , ROOT_DIR.'handler'.DS );
define('TPLDIR', ROOT_DIR.'template'.DS );  
define('SKNDIR', TPLDIR.'skin'.DS );    
define('MDLDIR', ROOT_DIR.'model'.DS );             
define('DBN', 'xxxxx' );        
define('HOST', 'xxxxx' );       
define('USR', 'xxxxx' );
define('PWD','xxxxx');
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

$paths = array(MDLDIR);
$isDevMode = false;

// the connection configuration
$dbParams = array(
    'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
    'host'      => HOST,
    'user'      => USR,
    'password'  => PWD,
    'dbname'    => DBN,
    'charset'   =>'utf8',
);

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode); 
$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
//$em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrinceTypeMapping('enum','string');

/*function exceptionHandler($exception){
    error_log($exception->getMessage());
} 

set_error_handler("exceptionHandler");*/
```

?>

I am trying to figure out what's wrong here in my `news.php` file.
Why did it not work out???
Could everyone help me???
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [Doctrine Annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html#doctrine-annotations) doc, add the `use` statement and check the right annotation (don't use a namespace for your class?), as example:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;

 /**
 *   @ORM\Entity 
 *   @ORM\Table(name="news")
 */
 class News{
 /**
 *  @nid 
 *  @ORM\Column(type="integer")  // **my id column is nid** 
 *  @ORM\GeneratedValue     
 */
 public $id;

 /** @author 
  * @ORM\Column(type="string")*/
 public $author;
```

Hope this help

Comment: no, nothing changes. My error still there. I don't use namespace now be cause i am  trying to make a core so that i will  make into my news cms.

Comment: How could i maping my table with name "Rich_news" with my entity named " news"????

Comment: Simply change the name in the table annotation

Comment: As you see above, i changed it. but not work at all. I tried to var_dump the schemas,  it returns array[10] with objects. But when i var_dump with  entities in doctrine , it returns array[0]. Doctrine red my database successfully. Yet when mapping with entity, it went wrong. I add as you recommended.